# How to insert data into a vertically partitioned table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with the partitioning of a table in the `SQL Server`. I have a table with over 103 columns out of which only 20 are used very frequently and are referenced by a number of tables.

As the table contains thousands of rows I have created a vertical partition and divided the table into multiple tables so as to save the table data in different file groups.

I have also created a view by joining those tables. And now, how do i insert data into different tables without using `INSTEAD OF` triggers?

Comment: Stored procedure? Instead of trigger on a view?

Comment: I don't want to use `INSTEAD OF` triggers or any triggers. Using a store procedure?? Can you please provide me with a bit more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stored procedure to encapsulate all your insert logic.

If you have, let's say, 3 tables that share same ID column and each have it additional columns, your stored procedure might look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Insert
(
    @Val1 VARCHAR(5)
  , @Val2 VARCHAR(5)
  , @Val3 VARCHAR(5)
)
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @id INT;

    INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1) VALUES (@Val1);

    SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, Col2) VALUES (@id, @Val2);
    INSERT INTO Table3 (ID, Col3) VALUES (@id, @Val3);

END
GO
```

**[SQLFiddle Working demo and sample tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02f73/1)**